# Check if hash contains any empty values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, hash

I have the following hash and I'm looking for an easy way to check if everything is empty in the hash. Not all values are always visible in the hash so sometimes the hash is without end_date / start_date or anything else.

```
test
=> {"0"=>
  {"_destroy"=>"",
   "START_DATE"=>"",
   "END_DATE"=>"",
   "EMPLOYER"=>"",
   "JOB_TITEL"=>"",
   "FUNCTIONAL_AREA"=>"",
   "INDUSTRY"=>"",
   "DESCRIPTION_TXT"=>"",
   "COUNTRY"=>"",
   "CITY"=>"",
   "REGION"=>"",
   "CONTRACT_TYPE"=>""},
 "1"=>
  {"_destroy"=>"",
   "START_DATE"=>"",
   "END_DATE"=>"",
   "EMPLOYER"=>"",
   "JOB_TITEL"=>"",
   "FUNCTIONAL_AREA"=>"",
   "INDUSTRY"=>"",
   "DESCRIPTION_TXT"=>"",
   "COUNTRY"=>"",
   "CITY"=>"",
   "REGION"=>"",
   "CONTRACT_TYPE"=>""},
 "2"=>
  {"_destroy"=>"",
   "START_DATE"=>"",
   "END_DATE"=>"",
   "EMPLOYER"=>"",
   "JOB_TITEL"=>"",
   "FUNCTIONAL_AREA"=>"",
   "INDUSTRY"=>"",
   "DESCRIPTION_TXT"=>"",
   "COUNTRY"=>"",
   "CITY"=>"",
   "REGION"=>"",
   "CONTRACT_TYPE"=>""}}
```

In pseudocode it would like this

```
Start loop
-> check if current position contains an empties 
=> if all is empty delete position
-> continue
end loop
```

**In this example it means that the hash will be empty at the end of the loop.**

Kind regards

Comment: Please do not paste a screen capture if it is text. Rather paste it as text.

Comment: I'm sorry I edited the topic and removed the picture. And pasted the code.

Comment: In the title, it says to check for any empty fields, and in the text, it says check if everything is empty. They mean different things. The latter entails the former.

Comment: I changed all to values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Hash#delete_if`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if):

```
test.delete_if { |i,h| h.all? { |k,v| v.empty? } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply this works as a charm! That's really awesome coding I thank you a lot!